# Manjaro Linux: I can't run Mariadb because missing socket

Tags: mysql, sockets, installation, mariadb, manjaro

Well, I have **Manjaro/Linux** 17.0, and I've tried to install MariaDB but I always get the same error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I don't know what to do, I've search in thousands of forums, I can't start the mariadb's deamon with **systemctl**, I tried to do a **touch** at **/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock** but then it refused my connection when I tried to start mariadb, and I tried to uninstall/reinstall MariaDB, but it's the same thing :(

In all my directories I can't find **mysql.sock** or similar.

Help me please!

Comment: Start by reading the error log.  The location varies but sometimes it's a `.err` file in `/var/log/mysql` or `/usr/local/mysql/data`.  The *actual* path of the socket file may be different or the error log should indicate more information.

Comment: You should be able to query: `show variables where variable_name = 'socket'` to view the socket path. If that is blank, then perhaps the server is not running?  The my.ini file should show the specified path with `socket=` variable in the file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solution which worked for me is https://serverfault.com/a/813123 , I just cleaned:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/*
```

then initialised the database:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a difference between what the server is using as the socket and what the client thinks should be the socket.

You can check the process list (`ps -ef | grep mysql`) and see if the server is running with a different socket setting than you expect. (Look for `--socket=`.)

Edit your `/etc/my.cnf`, find or make a `[client-server]` section, and set `socket` to a file that makes sense. It should be in a directory that users have access to. The default setting is `socket=/tmp/mysql.sock`, so that should be a safe bet. Then remove any other `socket` setting elsewhere in `/etc/my.cnf` or files in the `/etc/my.cnf.d/` directory. Then restart, and it should hopefully work.

Also check if you have a personal config file `~/.my.cnf`, look for a socket setting in there, and if so remove it.

For reference, see the [socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#socket) entry in the MariaDB KB. Also, have a look at the full list of locations where MariaDB config files could be stored [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/#location-in-linux-unix-mac).